# Blender Eevee material previews displaying as purple

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]Blender Eevee material previews displaying as purple (no textures), yet having set it to principled bsdf with a light blue colour. It displays correctly only in cycles. Also this problem started occurring after the latest few updates Blender 2.83 onward. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/91pp4BW2

Comment: hello, maybe pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If it works in previous version for you, than post it as a bug report or search for a report, it is probably mentioned already..

Comment: I Faked a user (click the shield next to the editable name), and the material updated, you can then remove the fake user. that worked for me anyways... definitely seems like a bug